# printing variable in js html

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<script type ="text/javascript">
    var current = 0;
</script>
                    

<h3 style={{marginTop: '10', textAlign: 'center'}}><b>Current Affect: <script type="text/javascript">document.write(current)</script></b></h3>
```

only outcome is "Current Affect:" can't print 0

Answer (score 1):

Your code does, in fact, produce the `0` that you should get although your approach uses techniques that are about 20+ years old and not how modern code is written.

`document.write()` is not recommended unless you are dynamically creating a new document in a new window.

Also, inline scripts are not an appropriate way to inject dynamic content into the page. Instead, create an HTML element that will act as a placeholder for the results and use the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) to populate the element.

Lastly, `type="text/javascript"` on `script` tags hasn't been needed in over 5 years.

```html
<h3 style={{marginTop: '10', textAlign: 'center'}}>Current Affect: <span id="result"></span></h3>

<script>
  var current = 0;
  // Access the HTML placeholder and populate it with the dynamic content
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = current;
</script>
```